# Mysterious Top Layer Artifacts

Tags: surface

It appears that some regions on my top layer has these weird patterns. It doesn't seem like over-extrusion because the extrusion lines go diagonally whereas these patterns look irregular and somehow "organic" to me. And, it only appears on some region.

[image: Pattern]

I am using EAUN PLA+ and the printer is Bambu Lab X1C. It has an enclosure. Filament seems quite dry, I have put them in storage box with silica for 3 days. Also I enabled top surface ironing, this might be the cause but I am not sure, as these artifacts only appear in this region.

Any idea?

Comment: This is underextrusion, it is interesting to see if this is caused by the ironing. Try printing again without. Furthermore, putting filament in silica for 3 days will not dry the filament, you need to add heat as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this sort of problem never happened again, so still unsure of the cause. Will keep an eye on it.